Worse results than baseline when fine-tuning with LoRA from Hugging Face, is there a mistake in my code?
I fine-tune DistilBERT using the library PEFT and obtain bad results compared to benchmark (70 instead of 85), is there a mistake in my code?
I use PEFT library from Hugging Face, I guess the issue might come from an initialization somewhere not needed or from the target modules in LoRA configuration.
import torch
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer, DistilBertForSequenceClassification, Trainer, TrainingArguments
from datasets import load_dataset
import evaluate
from peft import LoraConfig, get_peft_model

torch.cuda.is_available()
torch.cuda.current_device()

GLUE_data = 'mrpc'

# Load the model and tokenizer
model_name = "distilbert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model1 = DistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, num_labels=2)

# Check if CUDA is available and set the device accordingly
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Move the model to the GPU (if available)
model1 = model1.to(device)

# Define LoRA configuration
lora_config = LoraConfig(task_type="SEQ_CLS",
                       r=8,
                       lora_alpha=32,
                       lora_dropout=0.01,
                       target_modules=["q_lin", "k_lin","v_lin","out_lin"])
                       #target_modules = ['query_key_value'])

model = get_peft_model(model1, lora_config)

model.print_trainable_parameters()

# Load the dataset
dataset = load_dataset("glue", GLUE_data)

# Tokenize the dataset
def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["sentence1"], examples["sentence2"], truncation=True, padding=True)

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)

# Define the training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results_LoRA",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="no",
    #learning_rate=1e-5
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,  #if M1 has limited memory, so reduce batch size
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    logging_steps=100,
    fp16=True,  # Use mixed precision (float16) training to speed up
    report_to="none",  # Disable reporting (optional)
)

# Define a compute metrics function for evaluation
metric = evaluate.load("glue", GLUE_data)
def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    logits = torch.tensor(logits)  # Convert logits to a Tensor
    predictions = torch.argmax(logits, dim=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)

# Initialize the Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["validation"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

# Fine-tune the model
trainer.train()

# Save the model, tokenizer, and training arguments after training
trainer.save_model(f"./results_LoRA/{GLUE_data}")

tokenizer.save_pretrained(f"./results_LoRA/{GLUE_data}")

# Load the tokenizer and model from the saved checkpoint
trainer = f"./results_LoRA/{GLUE_data}"

# Load the tokenizer
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(trainer)

# Load the trained model
model = DistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(trainer)


# Initialize the Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["validation"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

# Evaluate the model
eval_results = trainer.evaluate()
print(f"Evaluation Results: {eval_results}")

I tried to change hyperparameters a lot without much success
